# Cause of phase shift in matterwave interferometers

Tags: interferometry

I am studying matterwave interferometry and I have read that the phase shift accumulated between the two arms of the interferometer is due to a coupling of the atoms to non-inertial forces. What is non-inertial here? The frame that the interferometer is in or the reference frame of the atoms? What is an example of a non-inertial force that produces a phase shift and an inertial force that does not?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the reference frame is the one of the interferometer; it does not make much sense to talk about reference frame of the atoms. For instance, if the interferometer is being rotated around the axis made by one of its arm, the matter in the other arm will be subject to a centrifugal force and this can induce a phase shift. On the other hand, if the axis of rotation is perpendicular to both of the arms, passing through the junction between the two, and if the arms are of same length, the centrifugal force will not induce a phase shift

Answer (score 0):

Gravity is the prime example to this.
Gravity accelerates the atoms and will introduce a phase shift.

Comment: Gravity also accelerates the remainder of the interferometer. At most you can measure tidal forces that way.

Comment: @FlatterMann The first light pulse atom interferometer already measured gravity. https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.67.181

Quote: "Using the interferometer as an inertial sensor, the acceleration of a sodium atom due to gravity has been measured with a resolution ..."

Comment: Was that interferometer in free fall? If not, then they were either measuring the acceleration of the floor against the interferometer or a tidal force from a nearby object.

Comment: @FlatterMann It's in free fall

Comment: Then it's a tidal force. There is no gravity in a free-falling system.

Comment: There is gravitational acceleration g, which explicitly appears in the measured phase shift. Do you take g as a result of the tidal force? If yes, could you explain to me the difference of tidal force and acceleration due to gravitational force?

Comment: Yes, that is the acceleration that the table and the floor apply to the experiment, but you said it's supposed to be in freefall.

Comment: The atoms are in free fall. The laser and the mirror are not.
What's the difference between tidal force and the acceleration due to gravitational force?

Comment: The instrument is not in free fall, then. What it's measuring is the acceleration of the floor. I know... gravity is weird.